# How to transform .jpg to .yuv

Tags: ffmpeg

Any help on transform the .jpg to .yuv?

I have a.jpg file, and I wanna read the file and transform to a.yuv.
How can I do it by using the ffmpeg?

Answer (score 2):

From `man ffmpeg` (modified slightly):

> You can output to a raw YUV420P file:
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -i mydivx.avi hugefile.yuv
> ```
>
> hugefile.yuv is a file containing raw YUV planar data. Each frame is
>   composed of the Y plane followed by the U and V planes at half
>   vertical and horizontal resolution.

Remember that ffmpeg usage questions are better suited for superuser.com (and therefore  you'll probably get better and more detailed answers there too).

Comment: @zerocool No, but you should have mentioned that in the question.